# Remove UIAlertController ending animation

Tags: swift, animation, uialertcontroller, dismiss

In my case, I need to show the user the UIAlertController upside down.

At the time of present, I can avoid the opening animation with:

```
present(alert, animated: false, completion: {
    alert.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
})
```

At this point, the user sees the inverted UIAlertController.

And at the time of closing, after clicking on Cancel, UIAlertController blinks in the normal position for a hundredth of a second, which slightly spoils the UX.

With this simple example, you can catch this slight blink:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Action", style: .default, handler: { action in })
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { action in })
alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(cancel)
present(alert, animated: false, completion: {
    alert.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
})
```

I tried to call

```
alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

or

```
alert.view.isHidden = true
```

inside cancel action, but it didn’t work.

Help me find a way to avoid this annoying end animation.

Comment: The problem is that you are not in charge of an alert's dismissal; it is automatic when the user taps a button. You'd be much better off with a custom presented view controller (which could look and act like an alert).

Comment: Bad, it seems that this is the only right solution.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with that idea. A UIAlertController _is_ a presented view controller, so it makes no difference. You are the one who is trying to misuse alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Just subclass UIAlertController like this:

```
class InstantCloseAlertController: UIAlertController {
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```